# R: adding in rows of zero based on the values in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, data-manipulation, zero

I am trying to append rows to an R data.frame. Here is an example of a data.frame "foo":

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   1   200
1   1   2   50
1   1   3   15
1   2   1   150
1   2   4   50
1   3   1   300
2   1   2   40
2   1   4   90
2   3   2   80
```

For every A, there are 3 possible values of B, and for every B, there are 4 possible values of C. However, the initial df only contains non-zero values of D. I'd like to manipulate the df so that zeros are included for both B and C. Thus, the df would show 0's in D for any value of B/C that was 0. I have seen questions that address this with one column, but couldn't find a question addressing it with multiple columns. The final df would look like this:

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   1   200
1   1   2   50
1   1   3   15
1   1   4   0
1   2   1   150
1   2   2   0
1   2   3   0
1   2   4   50
1   3   1   300
1   3   2   0
1   3   3   0
1   3   4   0
2   1   1   0
2   1   2   40
2   1   3   0
2   1   4   90
2   2   1   0
2   2   2   0
2   2   3   0
2   2   4   0
2   3   1   0
2   3   2   80
2   3   3   0
2   3   4   0
```

I first tried creating a dummy data frame that then merged with the initial df, but something isn't working right. Here's the current code, which I know is wrong because this code only generates rows based on A. I think I want to make the dummy frame based on A and B but I don't know how - could an if/else function work here?:

```
# create dummy df
dummy <- as.data.frame(
  cbind(
    sort(rep(unique(foo$A), 12)),
    rep(1:3,length(unique(foo$A)))))
colnames(dummy) <- c("A","B")
foo$A <- as.numeric(foo$A)
foo$B <- as.numeric(foo$C)

# merge with foo
mergedummy <- merge(dummy,foo,all.x=T)
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A one liner:

```
merge(dat, data.frame(table(dat[1:3]))[-4],all.y=TRUE)

#   A B C   D
#1  1 1 1 200
#2  1 1 2  50
#3  1 1 3  15
#4  1 1 4  NA
#...
```

Or maybe less complicated:

```
out <- data.frame(xtabs(D ~ ., data=dat))
out[do.call(order,out[1:3]),]

#   A B C Freq
#1  1 1 1  200
#7  1 1 2   50
#13 1 1 3   15
#19 1 1 4    0
#...
```

Where `dat` is:

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), B = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L), C = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L), D = c(200L, 50L, 15L, 150L, 50L, 300L, 40L, 90L, 
80L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Your first one-liner works, and then I added in an extra line of `df[is.na(df) <- 0` to replace the NAs with 0s. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I created a master data frame which includes all combinations of A, B, and C as you describe in the expected outcome. Then, I merge the master data frame and your data frame. Finally, I replaced NA with 0.

```
master <- data.frame(A = rep(1:2, each = 12),
                     B = rep(1:3, each = 4),
                     C = rep(1:4, times = 6))

library(dplyr)

master %>%
    left_join(., mydf) %>%
    mutate(D = ifelse(D %in% NA, 0, D))

#   A B C   D
#1  1 1 1 200
#2  1 1 2  50
#3  1 1 3  15
#4  1 1 4   0
#5  1 2 1 150
#6  1 2 2   0
#7  1 2 3   0
#8  1 2 4  50
#9  1 3 1 300
#10 1 3 2   0
#11 1 3 3   0
#12 1 3 4   0
#13 2 1 1   0
#14 2 1 2  40
#15 2 1 3   0
#16 2 1 4  90
#17 2 2 1   0
#18 2 2 2   0
#19 2 2 3   0
#20 2 2 4   0
#21 2 3 1   0
#22 2 3 2  80
#23 2 3 3   0
#24 2 3 4   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
foo <- merge(expand.grid(lapply(foo[,1:3], unique)), foo, all=TRUE, sort=TRUE)
foo[is.na(foo)] <- 0
```